# Generate Random numbers from tuple list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, random

I have a tuple list containing numbers with a certain probability assigned:

```
    import random
    my_randoms = [random.randrange(1, 51, 1) for _ in range(10)]

    weights = [0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.03, 0.15, 0.05, 0.2, 0.02, 0.09, 0.11]

    aa = list(zip(my_randoms, weights))    

    aa
        Out[40]: 
    [(7, 0.1),
 (5, 0.2),
 (47, 0.05),
 (21, 0.03),
 (13, 0.15),
 (32, 0.05),
 (41, 0.2),
 (1, 0.02),
 (47, 0.09),
 (19, 0.11)]
```

I would like to randomly generate 100 numbers from the list given the probability distribution that I assigned. How could I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to randomly take 100 numbers from the list containing 10 numbers? And get twice more `5`s than `7`s in the resulting list?

Comment: Hi Poolka! Yep, that's why I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you may use `random` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences):

```
random.choices(my_randoms, weights=weights, k=100)
```